# How to add one event listener for all buttons

Tags: javascript

How do I add an event listener to multiple buttons and get the value of each one depending on the one clicked. Eg:

```
<button id='but1'>
Button1
</button>
<button id='but2'>
Button2
</button>
<button id='but3'>
Button3
</button>
<button id='but4'>
Button4
</button>
```

So that on javascript, I wouldn't have to reference each button like:

```
Const but1 = document.getElementById('but1'); 
but1.addEventListener('click');
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't really need to add listeners to all the buttons. There is such thing in JS as [Bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) so you can wrap all your `buttons` with a `div` and catch all the events there. But make sure you check that the click was on a `button` and not on the `div`.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const isButton = event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON';
  if (!isButton) {
    return;
  }

  console.dir(event.target.id);
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <button id='but1'>
  Button1
  </button>
  <button id='but2'>
  Button2
  </button>
  <button id='but3'>
  Button3
  </button>
  <button id='but4'>
  Button4
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. The div also could get clicked, which then fires the event listener, which would call the function and give wrong values.

Comment: @amaugosomto you are right, I forgot about this. But you just need to check a type of clicked element and skip if it was not a button. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 14):

If the buttons do not have a common class, you can use:

```
button[id^=but]
```

To select any button with id starting with the phrase `but`, so it translates to `but*`, where * is a wildcard match.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button[id^=but]')

btns.forEach(btn => {

   btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
        console.log( event.target.id );
   });

});
```

```html
<button id='but1'>Button1</button>
<button id='but2'>Button2</button>
<button id='but3'>Button3</button>
<button id='but4'>Button4</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you could use a class instead of id to grab every button.

```
<button class="btn">
Button1
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button2
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button3
</button>
<button class="btn">
Button4
</button>
```

And then in JS:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
buttons.forEach(function(currentBtn){
  currentBtn.addEventListener('click', handleEvent)
})
```

You just loop over the buttons constant which hold a NodeList with all the buttons that were found.
[read about document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2):

Like Lucas's answer, this version will use classes instead of ID to select each button, and it will use a basic for loop.

```
<button class="btn">
    Button1
</button>
<button class="btn">
    Button2
</button>
<button class="btn">
    Button3
</button>
<button class="btn">
    Button4
</button>
```

The JS

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length;

for (var i = 0; i < buttons ; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("Button Clicked");
    });
}
```