# do i really have to add multiple event listener with multiple different arguments?

Tags: javascript, button, return, arguments, addeventlistener

```
        <body>

 <div id = "styleDiv">
 <p> add to cart <span id = "balls"> 25.99 </span> </p> 
 <p> add to cart <span id=  "racket"> 68.99 </span> </p>
 <p> add to cart <span id=  "grip"> 6.99 </span> </p>
 <button> price after tax </button>

 </div>


  <script>
  
  var btn = document.querySelector("button");
  var balls = document.querySelectorAll('#balls');
  var racket = document.querySelector('#racket');
  var grip = document.querySelector('#grip');
  
  btn.addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
  calcPrice(balls);
  })
  
    btn.addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
  calcPrice(racket);
  })
  
     btn.addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
  calcPrice(grip);
  })
  
 
    
    //***************************************** READING A NUMBER INSIDE THE PRGRAM WITH INNERHTML AND 
    THEN CONTROLLING DECIMAL LENGTH ******************************
   function calcPrice(element) {

 var price = element.innerHTML; 
 var tax = 0.175;// tax rate
 var fullPrice = (price * tax) + parseFloat(price); 

 fullPrice = fullPrice.toString(); 

 if (fullPrice.charAt(5) == "5") {  

 fullPrice = fullPrice.slice(0,5)+ "4";

 }
 fullPrice = Number(fullPrice);   
 var totalPrice = fullPrice.toFixed(2);

 element.innerHTML = totalPrice;

 return totalPrice;

 }
```

How do i shorten this code? so that i dont have to add multiple event listeners  the more different spans there are? Like if i plan to add 30 different spans , surely i havenet got to have 30 different event listeners.Id like add one event listener for all the different spans which will then pass the holding argument into the function , and then return the answer. Is this possible

thanks all

Comment: Why is it `.querySelectorAll('#balls')`? An id has to be unique (and `calcPrice()` can only handle single elements).

Comment: Just do the three calls in one event handler and either grab the elements in the event handler or pass a selector to `calcPrice()` and grab the elements there.

Comment: thanks, im still new in my learning, that querySelector All is a mistake , i dont know why thats there, typo/brain fog

Comment: Andread can you give me a quck example of doing the 3 calls in one ecent handler please ? so i know what you mean ? Ill accept your answer and give you a massive thank you

Comment: Use a list of ids, iterate over that list, grab the element with the current id, call `calcPrice()` with the current element. Add a common class to all the `<span>` element that you're interested in, grab them with `.querySelectorAll(".<the class>")`, iterate over the elements, call `calcPrice()` for every element. Use `.querySelectorAll()` to grab all `<span>` elements in `#styleDiv`, iterate over the elements, call `calcPrice()` for every element. ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add an event listener to each separate button. Depending on what you want to do, you can wrap your buttons in a `<div>` tag, and add a listener to this tag instead, in order to listen to all the buttons. However, you need to ensure that the button is actually pressed, and not just the `<div>`. You can see an example [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680484/how-to-add-one-event-listener-for-all-buttons)