# Any button clicked listener?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set listener for all buttons on page? Like

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
alert("button was clicked");
}​;​
```

But for all buttons at same time?

Best way to get same result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add one event listener for all buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680484/how-to-add-one-event-listener-for-all-buttons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With event delegation, you can add a listener to the whole document and check if the clicked target was a button:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(target);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>click 1</button>
<button>click 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTag("BUTTON");
buttons.forEach(function(v){
  v.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('i have been clicked');
  }
}
```

or with jQuery

```
$('button').on('click', function(){ console.log('i have been clicked'); }
```

and including inputs

```
$('button, input[type=submit]').on('click', function(){ console.log('i have been clicked'); }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**for onclick lisener**

<div id="test">
    click me
    <div>
    <script>
    
        $("#test").click(function(){
                  alert("clicked test");
        });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you using `jQuery`? Does the tag contain `jQuery`? If you answered a question, include the details of the script you answered, otherwise it will be very difficult for everyone (_maybe_) if want to learn it in the future. btw, Welcome to SO!