# How to make one modal work for multiple button

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's working but only in one button here's my code. When i click at first button it showed up but when i click on the other buttons it doesnt show up. it seems that only at the first buttons its working. I also used the class to call the modal but it seems it also doesnt work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Records</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body{
            background-image: url(wallpaper.jpg) ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            font-family: sans-serif;

        }
        .table-container{
            padding: 0 10%;
            margin: 40px auto 0;
        }
        .heading{
            font-size: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #000, 2px -2px 0 #000, -2px 2px 0 #000, 2px 2px 0 #000;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        .table{
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-spacing: 0;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #FFD700;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }
        .table thead{
            background-color: #FFD700;

        }
        .table thead tr th{
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: medium;
            letter-spacing: 0.35px;
            color: #000000;
            opacity: 1;
            padding: 12px;
            vertical-align: top;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        .table tbody tr td{
            font-size: 14px;
            letter-spacing: 0.35px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #000000;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #000000; 
        }
        table tr:first-child th:first-child,
        table.table tr:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        }

        table tr:first-child th:last-child,
        table.table tr:first-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        }

        table tr:last-child td:first-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        }
    
        table tr:last-child td:last-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        }


        .table tbody tr td .btn{
            width: 130px;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 35px;
            background-color:#ee2828;
            display: inline-block;
            font-weight: medium;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            user-select: none;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            font-size: 14px;
            opacity: 1;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .table tbody tr td .btn:hover{
            font-weight: bold;
        }


    .video-container {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 999999;
        background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .video-container .close{
        position: absolute;
        top:10%;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color:white;
    }
    .video-container video{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 800px;
        transform: scale(0);
        box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        outline: none;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .video-container.show{
        pointer-events: all;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .video-container.show video{
        transform: scale(1);
    }

@media(max-width: 768px){
    .table thead{
        display: none;
    }
    .table, .table tbody, .table tr, .table td{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .table tr{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .table tbody tr td{
        text-align: right;
        padding-left: 50%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .table td:before{
        content: attr(data-label);
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        padding-left: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
        <div class="video-container" id="videoContainer">
            <span class="close" id="close">&#10006;</span>
            <video src="video.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
        </div>
    

    <div class="table-container">
        <h1 class="heading">Video Records</h1>

        

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Video ID</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>#</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Video ID">0022332</td>
                    <td data-label="File Name">Videocapture.mp4</td>
                    <td data-label="Date">12 / 04 / 2021</td>
                    <td data-label="Time">11:34 PM</td>
                    <td data-label="#"><a href="#" class="btn">Play</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Video ID">0022311</td>
                    <td data-label="File Name">Videocapture1.mp4</td>
                    <td data-label="Date">12 / 04 / 2021</td>
                    <td data-label="Time">11:34 PM</td>
                    <td data-label="#"><a href="#"   class="btn">Play</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Video ID">0022131</td>
                    <td data-label="File Name">Videocapture2.mp4</td>
                    <td data-label="Date">12 / 04 / 2021</td>
                    <td data-label="Time">11:34 PM</td>
                    <td data-label="#"><a href="#"   class="btn">Play</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td data-label="Video ID">0025321</td>
                    <td data-label="File Name">Videocapture3.mp4</td>
                    <td data-label="Date">12 / 04 / 2021</td>
                    <td data-label="Time">11:34 PM</td>
                    <td data-label="#"><a href="#"   class="btn">Play</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    btn = document.getElementById("btn");

    videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer");

    close = document.getElementById("close");

    btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        videoContainer.classList.add('show');
    })

    close.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        videoContainer.classList.remove('show');
    })


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I think its because of my javascript so I kind of wondering if someone could help me to make it work in multiple buttons instead of one only

Comment: This question has been answered before: [How to add one event listener for all buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680484/how-to-add-one-event-listener-for-all-buttons)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add one event listener for all buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680484/how-to-add-one-event-listener-for-all-buttons)

Answer (score 2):

With `getElementById` you'll only get one HTML element. You should use `getElementByClassName` or `querySelectorAll` to get all the nodes that match the .class selector. And to attach event listenters to all the nodes in a NodeList object, you can use `forEach`.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(btn => { 
 btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  videoContainer.classList.add('show');
 }) 
})
```

Learn more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

[image]