# How to delete object from array when removed from DOM/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a library Web application that allows you to click a button that brings up a form to add a book via title, author, pages, and if you've read it or not. Each form input gets added to a "card" in the document via `createElement`/`appendChild` and also gets added to the `myLibrary` array via a constructor function. Here's my script:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const btn = document.getElementById("newBook");
const modalBtn = document.getElementById("modal-btn");
const title = document.getElementById("title");
const author = document.getElementById("author");
const pages = document.getElementById("pages");
const haveRead = document.getElementById("have-read");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
const cards = document.getElementById("cards");

let myLibrary = [];

// Book Constructor
function Book(title, author, pages, haveRead) {
  (this.title = title),
    (this.author = author),
    (this.pages = pages),
    (this.haveRead = haveRead);

  if (alreadyInLibrary(title)) {
    return alert("Sorry, it looks like this book is already in your library");
  }
  addBooKToLibrary(this);
}

// Adds book to array
const addBooKToLibrary = function (book) {
  myLibrary.push(book);
};

const book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowling", 123, "Unread");
const book2 = new Book("LotR", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 4214, "Read");
const book3 = new Book("No Country for Old Men", "Cormac McCarthy", 575, "Unread");

// Creates books for each card in the DOM
createCard = function () {
  cards.innerHTML = "";
  myLibrary.forEach((book) => {
    let html = `<div class="card"><p>${book.title}</p><p>${book.author}</p><p>${book.pages}</p><p>${book.haveRead}</p><button class="remove-btn" onclick="deleteBook(this)">Delete</div>`;
    cards.innerHTML += html;
  });
};

// Checks the array for already registered books
function alreadyInLibrary(title) {
  return myLibrary.some(function (el) {
    return el.title === title;
  });
}

modalBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const book = new Book(title.value, author.value, pages.value, haveRead.value);
  modal.style.display = "none";
  createCard();
});
```

I've added a "Delete" button to each book's card that calls a function to remove itself from the document:

```js
function deleteBook(el) {
  const element = el;
  element.parentNode.remove();
}
```

However, the book stays in the array even after the card is deleted, and I can't figure out how to implement a function that deletes the object from the array if it's not found in the document.

I've tried adding a unique ID to each book object in the `myLibrary` array to target the object with to delete it from the array, but couldn't get that to work. I've tried looping through the array and using an `if` statement to see if `myLibrary.title === book.title`, else remove it from the array, but that's not working either.

Comment: "I've tried adding a unique ID to each book object in the myLibrary array to target the object with to delete it from the array, but couldn't get that to work" - what did it do? This is probably a good method to take, as "implement a function that deletes the object from the array if it's not found in the DOM" is probably not a good method to take.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "how to implement a function that deletes object from the array if it's not found in the document" part? Why would you want to delete the object if it is _not_ in the document? I'd think one would want to remove the book from the array when the card is removed, and vice versa -- the card is conceptually a visual representation of the book in the array, is it not?

Comment: It looks like you are using `title` as an index, to uniquely identify an item in the library, based on the fact that that is what you pass to `alreadyInLibrary`?  So you should be able to [find the object's array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects) using the `title`, and then [delete it by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)?

Comment: I guess I just don't know how to implement this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working snippet.

#### Notes

- It is considered good practice to separate your JS and HTML, here that means removing the `onclick()`s in your HTML, and replacing them with `addEventListener`s in your JS.
- When a button is clicked, we need to identify the book it represents.  You are already using `title` to uniquely identify a book in `alreadyInLibrary()`, so we'll use that.  Let's add a class to the `p` that displays the title so we can do that: `<p class='title'>...</p>`.  Now we can search with `.getElementsByClassName('title')` to get the `p`, and [here's how to get the text of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/how-to-get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-using-javascript).
- But how to find the title of the *specific* button that was clicked?  We need to find the parent `card`, and then the title inside that.  There are a few options:

  - If we start from the button that was clicked, we can find the closest parent `.card`, and then find the `.title` on that card.  Here's an example of how to find the parent: [Find the closest ancestor element that has a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119673/find-the-closest-ancestor-element-that-has-a-specific-class), and here's an example of how to find our title element inside the parent card: [Get element inside element by class and ID - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815374/get-element-inside-element-by-class-and-id-javascript)
  - Alternatively, we can add a click handler to the `card`, instead of the `button`.  Inside an event handler `this` refers to the element which the event happened to, so in this case that would be the whole card.  So we can search the clicked card form the title using the same example linked above: [Get element inside element by class and ID - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815374/get-element-inside-element-by-class-and-id-javascript).

I've gone with the 2nd option in the code below, but either are fine.

```js
let myLibrary = [];
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

// Book Constructor
function Book(title, author, pages, haveRead) {
  (this.title = title),
    (this.author = author),
    (this.pages = pages),
    (this.haveRead = haveRead);

  addBooKToLibrary(this);
}

// Adds book to array
const addBooKToLibrary = function (book) {
  myLibrary.push(book);
};

const book1 = new Book("Harry Potter", "J.K. Rowling", 123, "Unread");
const book2 = new Book("LotR", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 4214, "Read");
const book3 = new Book("No Country for Old Men", "Cormac McCarthy", 575, "Unread");

// We want to add an event handler for each card.  cards is a nodelist,
// we need an array to iterate over:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall
Array.from(cards).forEach(function (card) {

    // Add event handler for each card
    card.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    
        // Since the handler is for the card, we need to ignore clicks 
        // everywhere except directly on buttons:
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680484/how-to-add-one-event-listener-for-all-buttons
        if (event.target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') {
            return;
        }

        // Find the title of the book being deleted by searching inside
        // the card that registered this click
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815374/get-element-inside-element-by-class-and-id-javascript
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/how-to-get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-using-javascript
        let p = this.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
        let title = p.textContent;

        // console.log(title);

        // Find the index of array element for this book
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects
        let index = myLibrary.findIndex(x => x.title === title);

        // Now remove this book from the array
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array
        myLibrary.splice(index, 1);

        // Just for debugging, show it really is removed from myLibrary
        console.dir(myLibrary);

        // And remove it from the page
        this.remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <p class='title'>Harry Potter</p>
        <p>J.K. Rowling</p>
        <p>123</p>
        <p>Unread</p>
        <button class="remove-btn">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <p class='title'>LotR</p>
        <p>J.R.R. Tolkien</p>
        <p>4214</p>
        <p>Read</p>
        <button class="remove-btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
        <p class='title'>No Country for Old Men</p>
        <p>Cormac McCarthy</p>
        <p>575</p>
        <p>Unread</p>
        <button class="remove-btn">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the tips. This has me on the right track, although it's still not working with my code. I'll have to review my functions tomorrow and ensure nothing is re-entering the books into the array, preventing them from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data-` attribute to store the title and then delete the book by it.
To do this, you will need to add a `data-title` attribute to a card like so

```
let html = `<div class="card" data-title="${book.title}"><p>${book.title}</p><p>${book.author}</p><p>${book.pages}</p><p>${book.haveRead}</p><button class="remove-btn" onclick="deleteBook(this)">Delete</div>`;
```

and then read the `data-title` attribute in your delete function:

```
function deleteBook(el) {
  // removing book by title
  const bookTitle = el.getAttribute("data-title");
  myLibrary = myLibrary.filter((book) => book.title !== bookTitle);
  const element = el;
  element.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: This helps, I've not used dataset before, but el.dataset.title is coming back undefined?